# python diff between two config files with ignore timestamps

Tags: python, diff

I want to make diff between two text-files, (config files) but when I make diff between dumped config and running config there are Timestamp (first two lines) and other lines are not changed. But my script evaluate this as a change.

How do you perform a diff with some lines ignored?

I tried to use `filecmp` module in python;

1. the script removed the first two lines from the dumped config file and from the running config file
2. then ran diff
3. and finally prepended the removed lines back onto the running config file

But that doesnt seem like the best way.

Comment: can you show those `Timestamp (first two lines)` ?

Comment: sure, 

!Command: show running-config
!Time: Tue Nov  6 04:46:58 2016

I want to delete lines above or ignore them, I have found other question like this but I need do this stuff in python2.x..

Thanks

Comment: what is `!Command: show running-config` ? is it similar for both two files?

Comment: Yes, that is same for both files. But Second line of file is timestamp. And is relatively more simple delete first two lines and make diff than delete only second line, I think.  also Thanks for response